# How to map Domain Object Properties to Columns

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have this domain class.

```
class Book {

    String code
    String description

    static mapping = {
        table 'Book'
        version false
    }
}
```

and I have table `BookStore` with columns `COD` and `DSC`.
I need map to this table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book implements Serializable {
        String code
    String description

    static mapping = {
        table 'BookStore'
        version false
        id composite: ['code']
        code column: 'COD'
        description column: 'DSC'
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Book)) {
            return false
        }
        other.code == code
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append code
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, the sections within Mapping in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) should help you

For your example, the following should work:

```
class Book {

    String code
    String description

    static mapping = {
        table 'BookStore'
        version false
        code column: 'COD'
        description column: 'DSC'
    }
}
```

Also, within DataSource.groovy, make `dbCreate = "update"` under the appropriate environment that you are using. Refer the documentation on [DataSource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource) for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: because I in your example the id didn't map 
I get this exception 
Error 2012-05-07 20:21:21,479 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table 'BookStore' add id number(19,0) not null
| Error 2012-05-07 20:21:21,479 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column

Comment: Could you give the full table description? I went by whatever you had given in the question.

Comment: You can create any table with only two columns COD and DSC, then try your example, it will not work because the id(default column that add grails) didn't map. 
Actually the problem is -to map id ,but in 'BookStore'  table we have only 2 columns,
I try to set id with composite key and then map but I don't know how to do it.